# How to use datefinder on multiple rows of a column which has complete paragraphs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe containing 2 columns counter & history as given below

```
*counter History*
1        Log Type: customer chat
         chat history:
            xxxxxxxxx
            xxxxxxx
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            May 10 2020 23:34:57 +GMT 05:30
            --------------------------------------------
            log type: Phone call
            issue type: xxxxxx
            issue:
             qqqqqqqqqqqq
             qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
             qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
             May 11 2020 08:54:54 + GMT 05:30
             ----------------------------------------------
             log type: phone call
             issue:
              eeeeeeeeeeeeee
              eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
              eeeeeeee
              eeeeeeeeeee
              eeeeeeeeeeee
              eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
              May 11 2020 14:58:54 + GMT 05:30
            ----------------------------------
2           Log Type: Phone call
            issue:
            xxxxxxxxx
            xxxxxxx
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            May 10 2020 23:34:57 +GMT 05:30
            --------------------------------------------
            log type: Phone call
            issue type: xxxxxx
            issue:
             qqqqqqqqqqqq
             qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
             qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
             May 11 2020 08:54:54 + GMT 05:30
             ----------------------------------------------
             log type: phone call
             issue:
               eeeeeeeeeeeeee
               eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
               eeeeeeee
               eeeeeeeeeee
               eeeeeeeeeeee
               eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
             May 12 2020 14:58:54 + GMT 05:30
            ----------------------------------------------
```

now i want to do a check that if the log type says phone call only then it should count the unique date stamp i.e. if 2 date stams are same the count should be 1 Time stamps in this case is not required.
The Desired output is given below

```
counter History                                                 count
0        Log Type: customer chat                                 1
         chat history:
            xxxxxxxxx
            xxxxxxx
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            May 10 2020 23:34:57 +GMT 05:30
            --------------------------------------------
            log type: Phone call
            issue type: xxxxxx
            issue:
             qqqqqqqqqqqq
             qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
             qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
             May 11 2020 08:54:54 + GMT 05:30
             ----------------------------------------------
             log type: phone call
             issue:
              eeeeeeeeeeeeee
              eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
              eeeeeeee
              eeeeeeeeeee
              eeeeeeeeeeee
              eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
              May 11 2020 14:58:54 + GMT 05:30
            ----------------------------------
1           Log Type: Phone call                                3
            issue:
            xxxxxxxxx
            xxxxxxx
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            May 10 2020 23:34:57 +GMT 05:30
            --------------------------------------------
            log type: Phone call
            issue type: xxxxxx
            issue:
             qqqqqqqqqqqq
             qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
             qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
             May 11 2020 08:54:54 + GMT 05:30
             ----------------------------------------------
             log type: phone call
             issue:
               eeeeeeeeeeeeee
               eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
               eeeeeeee
               eeeeeeeeeee
               eeeeeeeeeeee
               eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
             May 12 2020 14:58:54 + GMT 05:30
            ----------------------------------------------
```

code i used was

```
import datetime
from dateparser.search import search_dates
def extract_sentence(input, word):
    return ".".join((sentence for sentence in input.split("----") if word in sentence))
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
lst_3=[]
ind_1=[]
for i in range (0,len(df2('counter'):
    matches = search_dates(extract_sentence(df2['History'][i],'Phone call'))
    lst_4=[]
    for x in matches:
        date_string =  x[1]
        lst_4.append(date_string)
    lst_6=[]
    lst_5=[]
    for item in lst_4:
        lst_5.append(str(item))
    for i in lst_5:
        ab=i[0:10]
        lst_6.append(ab)
    res = [i for i in lst_6 if '2020' in i or '2019' in i or '2018' in i or '2017' in i or '2016' in i or '2015' in i]
    lst_8=[]
    lst_8=len(list(set(res)))
    lst_1=[]
    try:
        for match in matches:
            lst=match
            lst_1.append(lst)
    except TypeError:
        continue
    ind=i
    ind_1.append(ind)
    lst_2=len(list(set(lst_1)))
    lst_3.append(lst_2)
                
df3=pd.DataFrame({'Index1': ind_1,'Count3': lst_3})

df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2['Index1']= np.arange(len(df2))

df4=pd.merge(df2,df3[['Index1','Count3']],on='Index1',how='left')
```

error i am getting when i run this is given below

```
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

need help on this

Comment: I get what you want to do, but your code is hard to read, I don't understand the lst_X variables.

Comment: On what line is the error triggered ?

Comment: i am getting the error on ```  matches = search_dates(extract_sentence(df6['Case_History'][i],'Phone Log'))```

Comment: Please update your original post to add information.

Comment: Have looked at what is inside `matches` ? Because I applied `search_dates` to your data and it returns 3 datetime objects : one for 'May 11 2020' one for  '08:54:54 + GMT' and one for '05:30'. So it seem reasonable that error will happen.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Comment: I have given only 2 line items and the error as it is was also copied from the python itself so both of points which was asked is already in there